# Is it true that $(a+b)^x>a^x+b^x$ for three numbers $a,b,x>1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, exponential-function

This holds for if $x$ is natural nunbers greater than $1$ so i think it would work for every real nunber $x$ greater than $1$.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: The [Binomial Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) (valid for *real* exponents) might help

Comment: It does.   You can extend it to rationals with a bit of manipulation.  And the reals will follow by continuity.

Comment: Try to show $p^x+q^x<1$ for positive $p$ and $q$ such that $p+q=1$. For that, observe the monotonicity of $p^x$ as a function of $x$.

Comment: You don't even need the binomial theorem for rationals, you can do it with far less. No need for complicated solutions we can do it with high school math. If $n = \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor $ you can just divide both sides by $(a+b)^{n-x}$ and then directly apply the good ol' fashioned combinatorial binomial theorem. See my answer below. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3660511/is-it-true-that-abxaxbx-for-three-numbers-a-b-x1/3661097#3661097

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can we say that $\left(a+b\right)^{\alpha}>a^{\alpha}+b^{\alpha}$ for all $a,b>0$ and $\alpha>1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2544089/can-we-say-that-leftab-right-alphaa-alphab-alpha-for-all-a-b0)

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3087519.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right. It's true for any reals $x>1$ and non-negatives $a$ and $b$.

Indeed, let $f(t)=t^x$, where $t\geq0$.

Thus, $f$ is a convex function.

We can assume that $a\geq b$.

Thus, since $$(a+b,0)\succ(a,b),$$ by Karamata we obtain:
$$f(a+b)+f(0)\geq f(a)+f(b)$$ or
$$(a+b)^x\geq a^x+b^x.$$

Comment: Note that $t^x$ is not necessarily convex. For example, $t^3$.

Comment: @Ahmad on $[0,+\infty)$ $t^3$ is a convex function. See please better my post. OK. I added this. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, that is right. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: The question is a duplicate, and you answered it before: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3087526.

Answer (score 0):

I am turning my previous comment into an answer.

Dividing both sides by $(a+b)^x$, the original inequality is equivalent to 
$$p^x+q^x<1,\quad \forall p>0,  q>0 \ni p+q=1, x>1.$$

We now demonstrate the last statement.

$u^x$ decreases with respect to $x$ for $u\in(0,1)$. So
$$p^x+q^x<p^1+q^1=1, \,\forall x>1;$$
and
$$p^x+q^x<p^1+q^1=1,\,\forall x<1.$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple proof using the binomial theorem:

Let $n = \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor$, then we have that 
\begin{equation}
(a+b)^x = (a+b)^{x-n }\sum_{k =0}^n \binom{n}{k } a^{n-k}b^{k},
\end{equation}
and therefore it is enough to prove that 
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k =0}^n \binom{n}{k } a^{n-k}b^{k} > \frac{a^x}{(a+b)^{x -n}} + \frac{b^x}{(a+b)^{x-n}},
\end{equation}
**If $x- n =  0$ then we are done. The proof is as trivial as noticing that $a^x$ and $b^x$ are two terms on the left. Therefore assume $x- n \neq  0$.**

Towards that end notice that since $a,b>0$ we have that 
\begin{equation}
\frac{a^{x-n}}{(a+b)^{x-n}} < 1
\end{equation}
and likewise 
\begin{equation}
\frac{b^{x -n}}{(a+b)^{x-n}} < 1
\end{equation}
since $y^\alpha$ is a strictly increasing function of $y$.
Therefore we have that 
\begin{equation}
\frac{a^{x}}{(a+b)^{x-n}} 
+
\frac{b^{x}}{(a+b)^{x-n}}  
< 
a^n
+
b^n
\end{equation}
which implies
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k =0}^n \binom{n}{k } a^{n-k}b^{k} \geq a^n +b^n >\frac{a^{x}}{(a+b)^{x-n}} 
+
\frac{b^{x}}{(a+b)^{x-n}}   ,
\end{equation}
as was needed.